# my controller spec on email confirmation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Here Im testing email confirmation fails. In dev mode everything works just ok. And I think that I've missed some configurations.

```
context 'with valid provider data' do
  before { session["devise.provider_data"] = { provider: 'twitter', uid: '123456' } }
  it "sends email confirmation" do
    expect{ post :create, authorization: { email: "user@email.com" } }.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

And the error

```
Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, authorization: { email: "user@email.com" } }.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count).by(1)
   expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

Coul anybody help with this?

```
context 'with valid provider data' do
  before { session["devise.provider_data"] = { provider: 'twitter', uid: '123456' } }
  before(:each) do
    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
    ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end

  after(:each) do
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end

  it "sends email confirmation" do
    expect{ post :create, authorization: { email: "user@email.com" } }.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some configuration. I usually do the setup in a before and after callback before tests that test email behaviour, such as:

```
before(:each) do
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
end

after(:each) do
  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
end
```

If you want the above configuration to apply to all your test suite, you could include it in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` file in the configure block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ....      

  config.before(:suite) do
      ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
      ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
      ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end
end
```

Comment: worked for me! I am a begginer, so would you mind, to tell if there is any way to put this stuff into config cause I run that directly in spec(sorry for my English) I updated question with the example